# Xamarin.iOS error when deploying to device

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to debug my app on a device but I keep receiving this error:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'NativeLibrary, Version=1.0.7837.29434, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (MT2002)
```

At some point in the past I managed to have it running on my device but at some point it stopped working. When I see the official documentation it seems it is a generic error and not sure what NativeLibrary stands for in this context (Mono?)

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin.Forms

Comment: You have a reference that it cannot resolve. Check your csproj file

Comment: Going to check that, thanks. I'm curious on why it works on simulator though